# Apache directory-server maven packaging

Tags: java, apache, maven, directory-server

I've checked out the latest [Apache Directory-server trunk](https://github.com/apache/directory-server) and am trying to get packaging working. I made a trivial change (i.e. added a new class) in `protocol-ntp`. When I run `mvn package` in `protocol-ntp`, the resulting jar in `target` contains the new class.

However, I'm having trouble getting the new class to be present in the jar containing all the projects. When I run `mvn package` inside the `all` folder, it "successfully" packages but the jar file (which does have an updated timestamp) contains only the old projects, without the new class. Running `mvn package` in the trunk root directory yields the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.apache.directory.ldap.client.template.LdapConnectionTemplateTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.718 sec - in org.apache.directory.ldap.client.template.LdapConnectionTemplateTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.AdsSchemaLoaderTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.378 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.AdsSchemaLoaderTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LdapConnectionPoolTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 5.171 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LdapConnectionPoolTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LdapConnectionTest
Tests run: 13, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 64.625 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LdapConnectionTest
testConnectionWrongHost(org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LdapConnectionTest)  Time elapsed: 30.056 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.integ.FrameworkRunner.runChild(FrameworkRunner.java:391)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.integ.FrameworkRunner.runChild(FrameworkRunner.java:64)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.integ.FrameworkRunner.run(FrameworkRunner.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LdapSSLConnectionTest
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.409 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LdapSSLConnectionTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LightweightLdapConnectionPoolTest
Max Active connections =: 8
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 5, Time elapsed: 3.851 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.LightweightLdapConnectionPoolTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.bind.SimpleBindRequestTest
Tests run: 21, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.147 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.bind.SimpleBindRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientAbandonRequestTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 36.442 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientAbandonRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientAddRequestTest
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.067 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientAddRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientCompareRequestTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.913 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientCompareRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientDeleteRequestTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 4.525 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientDeleteRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientExtendedRequestTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.875 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientExtendedRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientModifyDnRequestTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 4.896 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientModifyDnRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientModifyRequestTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.234 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ClientModifyRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ConcurrentSearchAndUnbindTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 4.257 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.ConcurrentSearchAndUnbindTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.GetRootDseTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.234 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.GetRootDseTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.AnonymousClientSearchRequestTest
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.928 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.AnonymousClientSearchRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.ClientSearchRequestTest
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 5.169 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.ClientSearchRequestTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.OperationWithIndexTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 21.043 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.OperationWithIndexTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.SearchRequestReturningAttributesTest
Tests run: 13, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.254 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.SearchRequestReturningAttributesTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.SearchWithReferralsTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.803 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.operations.search.SearchWithReferralsTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.ServerSchemaLoaderTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.399 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.ServerSchemaLoaderTest
Running org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.ValidatingLdapConnectionPoolTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.835 sec - in org.apache.directory.shared.client.api.ValidatingLdapConnectionPoolTest

Results :

Failed tests: 
  LdapConnectionTest.testConnectionWrongHost Expected exception: org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException

Tests run: 162, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 14

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ApacheDS Protocol Ntp .............................. SUCCESS [  4.451 s]
[INFO] Apacheds Server Annotations ........................ SUCCESS [ 34.057 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Server Config ............................. SUCCESS [ 12.769 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Server JNDI ............................... SUCCESS [  1.720 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Test Framework ............................ SUCCESS [01:09 min]
[INFO] ApacheDS All ....................................... SUCCESS [  3.743 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Logger Interceptor ........................ SUCCESS [  1.962 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Password Hashing Interceptor .............. SUCCESS [  1.046 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Core Integration .......................... SUCCESS [14:02 min]
[INFO] ApacheDS Protocol Kerberos Test .................... SUCCESS [ 27.092 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Server Integration ........................ SUCCESS [10:50 min]
[INFO] ApacheDS DirectoryService-WebApp bridge ............ SUCCESS [  0.723 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Jetty HTTP Server Integration ............. SUCCESS [  1.341 s]
[INFO] ApacheDS Service Builder ........................... SUCCESS [  3.739 s]
[INFO] Apache Directory LDAP Client API test .............. FAILURE [03:44 min]
[INFO] kerberos-client .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ApacheDS Service ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ApacheDS Wrapper ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ApacheDS Installers Maven Plugin ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ApacheDS Installers ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ApacheDS OSGi Integration Tests .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-25T21:53:52-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 118M/1407M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project ldap-client-test: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /media/DataDrive/Projects/Parclock/git-repos/directory-server/ldap-client-test/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ldap-client-test
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: You should fix the test...or the code depends on what the real root cause is..

Comment: The test err is present with no change to trunk. I'll submit a big report.

Comment: Why not using release versions of the artifacts?

Comment: I need to make a change to the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by running `mvn package` in the root project directory with `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`